# After GPU drivers update i get black screen before Windowns login

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

I just installed Windows 10 and after reboot my screen went black before login screen, i don't have mouse cursor and screen acts like it is not even conected but, i can go to BIOS or run Windows in safe mode if i change GPU drivers to one from installation it runs but only in 800x600 resolution and i'm unable to play games. My GPU is Radeon RX480

Comment: Have you installed [this driver](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-400-series/radeon-rx-400-series/radeon-rx-480)?

Comment: Yes it didn't work neither